# How can i change dynamically the content tab of jquery ui accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the next code:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Row 1</h3>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <h3>Row 2</h3>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <h3>Row 3</h3>
    <div id="3"></div>
</div>

$("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    clearStyle: true,
    active: 0,
    change: function(event, ui) {
    $("div#2").append('<p>Test</p>');
    }
});
```

When the accordion is clicked in another row, i want to fill the `<div id="2">` with data. On change event i am trying this:

```
$("div #2").append('<p>Test</p>');
```

But the text "Test" is printed inside the h3 instead the div... how can i achieve to print the text on the div???

I am using jquery 1.9.0

It seems like a bug http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4469#comment:4 isnt it?

Comment: Please show the rest of your related HTML (if any), and the part "On change event i am trying this"

Comment: I don't know what you're seeing, but there is no `change` option that you can pass to the `.accordion()` widget - http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ . Here's an example of it working with a button being clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/BrRPz/

Comment: Even though the `change` option isn't documented, it still works here: http://jsfiddle.net/BrRPz/1/

Comment: Or even with your specific code: http://jsfiddle.net/BrRPz/2/

Comment: let me try it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to redo the values you set for the `id` attributes. Try:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="header1">Row 1</h3>
    <div id="content1"></div>
    <h3 id="header2">Row 2</h3>
    <div id="content2"></div>
    <h3 id="header3">Row 3</h3>
    <div id="content3"></div>
</div>
```

That way, you can easily target which:

```
$("#content2").append('<p>Test</p>');
```

(or actually use `.append()`)

This is because the `id` attribute must be unique in order to target the element you actually want. jQuery will use the native `document.getElementById` method that will return the **first** found element with that `id`.

**UPDATE:**

Per your new edit, you need to use the selector without a space:

```
$("div#2").append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Although you do not need to include the `div` part of the selector. Just use:

```
$("#2").append('<p>Test</p>');
```

While HTML5 does allow the `id` to start with a number (and be 1 character long), I would suggest using a more descriptive `id`, like before I said: "content1", etc.

**UPDATE 2:**

Looking it over again, the `$("div #2")` should actually work as well, since the element with the `id` "2" **is** in a `<div>`. So technically that selector should work. Nonetheless, I'd still suggest a selector that isn't a number and is more descriptive.

With your code, I got it working with a more descriptive selector anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/BrRPz/2/

Comment: sorry for the misunderstood, but i dont have any ids on the h3

Comment: @FernandoSantiago I updated. You need to use the selector without a space (and even without the "div" part)

Comment: I already tried and it does'nt work, it seems like if it is a bug of the jquery ui accordion

Answer (score 0):

In css, id selector is unique element. so don't repeat a same id in the page

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="1">Row 1</h3>
    <div class="1"></div>
    <h3 id="2">Row 2</h3>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <h3 id="3">Row 3</h3>
    <div class="3"></div>
</div>
```

use script as

```
$("div.2").append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Note:
**id selector is unique element.**

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("div#2").append('<p>Test</p>');`

`$("div #2")` will target an element with `id='2'` inside of a `<div>` element, whereas `$("div#2")` targets a `<div>` with `id='2'`.